# Where to put data annotations tags?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-2

I am going through pro asp.net mvc 2.0 framework and it seems that he puts his data annotation tags on classes that also generate the linq to sql.

```
  [Table(Name = "Products")]
    public class Product
    {
        [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
        [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
        public int ProductID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a product name")]
        [Column] public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a description")]
        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        [Column] public string Description { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Range(0.01, double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a positive price")]
        [Column] public decimal Price { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please specify a category")]
        [Column] public string Category { get; set; }

        [Column]
        public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)] [Column]
        public string ImageMimeType { get; set; }
```

However I am wondering what happens if I don't develop my database this way. What happens if I just add to my solution a linqtosql.dbml ( linq to sql class) file where I get that nice designer.

Where would I put all these data annotations would I make another class what would have all this content in? Or maybe in the view models?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried using the MetadataType attribute?

```
public class IProductMetadata
{         
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    int ProductID;

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a product name")]         
    string Name;

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a description")]         
    string Description;
    // etc
}

[MetadataType(typeof(IProductMetadata))]
public partial class Product
{
}
```

I use this to attach attributes to properties on generated code through the partial class.  It works really well!

Comment: So basically your making partial class for each of your generated tables and then in this partial classes putting the validation data?

Comment: You make an interface that defines includes the validation attribute for all your properties, and then create a partial class that has MetadataType attribute.  When you give the partial class the MetadataType attribute, the property attributes are applied to the appropriate properties for that class.  Look http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx or http://goneale.com/2009/03/04/using-metadatatype-attribute-with-aspnet-mvc-xval-validation-framework/ for examples.

Answer (score 0):

I do it on the view model and use AutoMapper to map between data object and the view model.

Comment: Obviously this is your choice. But my opinion is you are validating business rules in the application layer which means your model is not portable. what if you wanted a different front end - for say a mobile device?

Comment: You can make a case for ValidationAttributes on the business object, but I don't see a compelling one for the DisplayAttributes.  Also, if he is using the designer to generate his classes, then he won't want to add DataAnnotations to them because they will get lost every time the template regenerates the classes.

Comment: The author of the book does not use the template he uses what I posted above. I am trying to figure out how where to put it if I use the template(and like you said that gets regenerated each time unless you make partial classes)

Comment: If you are going to be using your data model for views, go with Kirk's answer.  If you are going to be using view models, then you need to put it on the view model.